# coalesce converts non-unicode characters to question marks

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Migrating application from `SQL Server 2012` to `SQL Server 2017`.

I run the following 2 queries for data import (`Name` is `varchar` column containing non-english letters).

```
select Name from RemoteServer.RemoteDB.dbo.RemoteView
select coalesce(Name,'') from RemoteServer.RemoteDB.dbo.RemoteView
```

On SQL 2012 results are identical. On SQL 2017 I see the following:

[image: 1]

What can be the reason?

Unfortunately, I cannot change data types on remote server to `nvarchar`.

**UPDATE**: more info.

Linked server properties are the same (scripted the linked server on `SQL 2012` and created it on `SQL 2017` using that script).

On both servers (for historical reasons) server collation (and collation of system databases) is `Cyrillic_General_CI_AS`, my database collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CI_AS`.

On remote server both server and database collations are `Cyrillic_General_CI_AS`.

On `SQL 2012` both queries show data in context of any database.

On `SQL 2017` it works well on system databases and as showed above on my database. So, it is database collation dependent.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You believe the problem is `COALEASE`, however, it's this: *"Unfortunately, I cannot change data types on remote server to nvarchar."* If the datatype on your other server is `varchar` it's not `COALESCE` that is causing the problem, the data has already been lost. A `varchar` **cannot** store non-ANSI characters. As soon as you inserted those non-ANSI character into a `varchar` the data was lost. If you can't change the data type, then there is nothing you can do other than store all the characters that aren't ANSI characters as a `'?'`.

Comment: Have you compared collations of your local databases between 2012 and 2017? I mean databases in which context you execute the query. Also, have you tried to explicitly specify `collate Cyrillic_General_CI_AS` (for example) for the remote column?

Comment: Also, there is a fair chance that linked server's properties are different on 2012 and 2017. In particular, I would look for `Use remote collation` and other related options.

Comment: A `varchar` column can store non-ANSI characters, see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7e954e2a06e8680b53e3682dd7b8868d

Comment: @RogerWolf, see question update.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the coalesce function which basically only returns the first non-null value, the problem is the varchar datatype instead of nvarchar, but even, when you are using nvarchar you should use N'Languageword', here an example for proof you.

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE
(
   RussianCol VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @Table ( RussianCol )
VALUES ( 'спасбо' -- RussianCol - varchar(100)
       ),('Помогите')

SELECT * FROM @Table
```

Comment: I think you meant `RussianCol NVARCHAR(100)`, if you meant to demonstrate that `SELECT 'спасбо';` would returned as `'??????'`.

Comment: I wanted to prove how the varchar datatype avoids to store Russian characters and return ???

Comment: Then you'll want to use `N'спасбо'` and `N'Помогите'`. A literal string without the `N` prefix is treated as a `varchar`, so in your sample SQL, the characters are lost before they are even inserted (as the literal string is a `varchar`).

Comment: I believe that I do not explain me clearly, my example wanted to show aleyush that it is not possible to store Russian character with a varchar datatype as he affirmed at the beginning.  In my answer I mentioned: "when you are using nvarchar you should use N'Languageword'"

Comment: But you aren't using a literal `nvarchar` in your example here. That is my point. If you use `RussianCol NVARCHAR(100)` the values in the table would **still** be represented by `'?'`'s. Have a look at this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7b8a3f7cf12d7d0e546f71de14dd5ce8), which demonstrates.

Comment: Great discussion!
But your example works well in my environment: letters are successfully inserted and selected.
So does the example from db<>fiddle - it works in my environment without any question marks.
So, it is environment specific (collation specific?).

Comment: Here is an example of successfully storing russian letters in varchar column: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7e954e2a06e8680b53e3682dd7b8868d

Comment: Yes, it is related to the collation, using the same example that you posted, if you remove the collation it doesn't work, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=25291d3c60b125ccaac139fd3ac3c165

Comment: @GeovannyHernandez So, your comment "it is not possible to store Russian character with a varchar datatype" is not correct. It is possible, for some collations.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a setup to test, but you can try:

```
select coalesce(Name collate Cyrillic_General_CI_AS,'')
from RemoteServer.RemoteDB.dbo.RemoteView;
```

Comment: That did not work. But `coalesce(Name collate database_default, '')` works well. Interesting...